# Incomplete URL returned from application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am creating an application in VS2013, using VB and webforms.  I came to discover that the support for webforms is quite reduced, everybody seems to be going the MVC way.  Anyway the issue I am having is request URL misses out the application name in the URL.  As an example what what my problem is on my development machine it returns the complete URL but, on the test server where I created it as an application on IIS it misses out the application name, this make the link incomplete.

It returns
http://tsv/Account/Forgot.aspx

instead of 
http://tsv/itstock/Account/Forgot.aspx

tsv is the name for my local test server
How can i make it include itstock to make my URL complete

The code that gives the error is found in the IdentityModels.vb

```
Public Shared Function GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code As String, request As HttpRequest) As String

Dim absoluteUri = "/Account/ResetPassword?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)

        Return New Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString()

End Function
```

NB: I am using ASPNET Identity.

Comment: I can't really understand your issue enough to suggest a solution but note that support for webforms is not reduced - it is still fully supported

Comment: I have edited my post by adding the the code that has the issue.   It just that on the test server, the application name in this case ITSTOCk is missed out of the URL.

Comment: Wild guess (been long since I did ASP.NET): Add a tilde in your path. Dim absoluteUri = "~/Account/ResetPassword?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)

Comment: I already did that last week and this is what i got: http://tsv/itstock/Account/~/Account/ResetPassword?code=uPYF. 

Note the tilde in between. How do I resolve the tilde in between.

Comment: I also noticed @MattWilko that the tilde (~) is not resolved in the class.  it is resolved in the page, not in a class. ANY HELP PLZZZZ.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about prefixing the string? or is this a dynamic url? Try the below:

```
Public Shared Function GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code As String, request As HttpRequest) As String
```

Dim absoluteUri = "***/itstock***/Account/ResetPassword?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)

```
Return New Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString()

End Function
```